# Android unlock screen by power button or by sliding

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I wrote an Android app and I'm disapppointed about the unlock behaviour:

On my phone I use the slide lock screen.

If I lock the screen in my app by pressing the power button, the phone screen gets locked.

If I now press the power button again the phone is unlocked and directly returns to the app. But I want that the slide gesture is needed to unlock.

For all other apps of the phone I need the slide gesture to unlock after pressing the power button. So I assume that the unwanted behaviour is due to my app preferences, but I don't now which preferences are resposible. How can I have a sliding unlock for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I found the codeline which is resonsible for this behaviour. In my MainActivity in onCreate I added the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD. If I remove this line, my app uses the "unsecure" slide screen again. That is what I was looking for.

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity {


  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    getWindow ().addFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); //remove this line

  }
}
```